# How to urlencode a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, urlencode

I have searched hi and low for a solution.  I have a dynamic multidimensional array I need to break up and urlencode.  The number of items will change but they will always have the same keys.

```
$formFields = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [form_name] => productID [form_value] => 13 ) 
[1] => Array ( [form_name] => campaign [form_value] => email@gmail.com ) 
[2] => Array ( [form_name] => redirect [form_value] => http://example.com ) )
```

Each array has a Form Name and a Form Value.

This is what I'm trying to get to:

```
$desired_results = 
productID => 13
campaign => email@gmail.com
redirect => http://example.com
```

Every time I try and split them up I end up with: form_name => productID or something like that.

I'm trying to take the results and then urlencode them:

```
productID=13&campaign=email&gmail.com&redirect=http://example.com&
```

Comment: why not simply `$fromFields = array( 'productID' => 13, ...)` ?

Comment: The script won't know what the keys are.  They will change depending on which page is calling it.  This is meta data store in a wordpress and depending on which post is calling the script.. The $keys will change.

Comment: Maybe somebody has a suggestion on a better way to store the dynamic array in order to call it easier.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: As on version 4.4.3, there is a method named urlencode_deep. Can you try that and see if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return the values regardless of the names of the keys.

```
$result = array();

foreach ($formFields as $key => $value)
{
  $tmp = array_values($value);
  $result[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
print(http_build_query($result));
```

The `foreach` loops through the main array, storing the subarrrays in the variable `$value`. The function [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) return all the values from each array as a new numeric array. The value of [form_name] will be stored in the first index, [form_value] in the second.

The built in [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function will return a urlencoded string.

Comment: WOW That worked!  I don't understand it yet but it works!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 23):

you can use serialize and the unserialize:

```
$str = urlencode(serialize($formFields));
```

and then to decode it:

```
$formFields = unserialize(urldecode($str));
```

Comment: If it's just an array, `json_encode()` / `json_decode()` is preferrable to `serialize()` as it has a simpler structure and results in a shorter string. It's also more portable (like to `JS`and such)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my straightforward function for doing such a thing:

```
function array_urlencode($data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach($data as $k => $v) $data_temp[urlencode($k)]=array_urlencode($v);
        return $data_temp;
    } else {
        return urlencode($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- Encode entire array here -->

function encode(&$item, $key) {
$item = rawurlencode($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($input_array, 'encode');
```

Comment: It returns Array.